# Regarding subdomain without parent domain

Tags: dns, lookup

I received an email from mails.sukshmailers.com but if try to lookup (find ip address)sushmailers.com it shows no record exists 
but if try lookup for mails.sukshmailers.com record exists

My question is can domain name contain (.) dot symbol like mails.sukshmailers

if mails.sukshmailers.com is subdomain of sukshmailers.com why 
can't i find ip address of sukshmailers.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the dot is used to separate domain name parts, it cannot be part of a name. The whole system would get ambiguous that way.

If dots are used, they have to be represented in a special way - from https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt:

> The labels in the domain name are expressed as character strings and
>   separated by dots.  Quoting conventions allow arbitrary characters to be
>   stored in domain names.

There is nothing wrong with the "naked" domain name not having an IP assigned to it. This is the initial state of every new domain.

Whether the domain itself is valid, i.e. registered by someone, depends on `whois` information, which is available for the domain you mention.

Comment: It actually _is_ possible to have a "dot" character inside a  label - but in presentation format it would have to be "escaped" to disambiguate it from the "dot" that separates labels.